# TTImageView inside UIScrollview not receiving touches

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I am having an issue with TTImagViews inside UIScrollview. I searched high and low, but coul'dnt really find a solution. Interestingly, the tap gesture works on the last TTImageview inside the scrollview. For instance i have 10 images, that the user can scroll and the **touch gesture works only on the 10th image on page 2 or rather, the last image**. This is my code; any suggestions?

```
 UIScrollView *imageScroll=[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, postMessageLabel.frame.size.height+10, 250, 78)];
    [imageScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(70 * ([[images objectAtIndex:0]count])+10,64)];        
    int startAtX=5;
    for(int i=0;i<[[images objectAtIndex:0]count];i++){
        if([[GlobalFunctions sharedGlobalFunctions] isValidURL:[[images objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:i]]){
            TTImageView *imageView=[[TTImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(startAtX, 5, 64, 64)] ;
            imageView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;  
            [imageView addGestureRecognizer:thumbnailTap];                 
            imageView.urlPath=[[images objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:i];
            imageView.autoresizesToImage=NO;
            imageView.defaultImage=nil;
            imageView.delegate=self;    
            [imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
            [imageScroll addSubview:imageView];
            [imageView release];

        }
            startAtX+=70;            
    }

    [imageScroll setBounces:YES];
    [imageScroll setDelaysContentTouches:YES];
    [imageScroll setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:imageScroll];
    [imageScroll release];
```

And yeah, the tap gesture works perfectly if there is only one ttimageview inside the uiscrollview. I have no clue why!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Looks' like there is nothing wrong with my code; the only difference is how i am attaching the gesture recognizer. Even though i fixed i am not sure about why it went wrong. This is what happened

1. I have declared a gesture recognizer in my viewdidload with the typical alloc init.
2. Hence, i assumed, the gesture recognizer is available througout the view. I just kept adding it to a loop of images.

Step 2; seemed to be the problem. The problem went away when i declared a gesture recognizer for each and every image and released it after assigning it.

So technically for each image

```
---Create a gesture recognizer
   |-Attach it to the TTImageView
---Release the gesture recognizer
```

That solved the problem. But am still curious, why the gesture recognizer works when assigned to a single and image and fails when i assign it to multiple imageviews.

Thanks Abdullah for trying, but your solution got me nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

Add image view inside UIView and then add tap gesture to that UIView. This worked for me and will also worked for you. Try the followings:

```
UIScrollView *imageScroll=[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, postMessageLabel.frame.size.height+10, 250, 78)];
    [imageScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(70 * ([[images objectAtIndex:0]count])+10,64)];        
    int startAtX=5;
    for(int i=0;i<[[images objectAtIndex:0]count];i++){
        if([[GlobalFunctions sharedGlobalFunctions] isValidURL:[[images objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:i]]){
            TTImageView *imageView=[[TTImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 64, 64)] ;
            imageView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;  
            [imageView addGestureRecognizer:thumbnailTap];                 
            imageView.urlPath=[[images objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:i];
            imageView.autoresizesToImage=NO;
            imageView.defaultImage=nil;
            imageView.delegate=self;    
            [imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

UIView *viewWithImg=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(startAtX, 5, 64, 64)];
        [viewWithImg addSubview:imgView];
        viewWithImg.tag=i;
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture2 =
        [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapGestureCaptured2:)];        
        tapGesture2.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        tapGesture2.numberOfTouchesRequired=1;
        [viewWithImg addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture2];

            [imageScroll addSubview: viewWithImg];
            [imageView release];

        }
            startAtX+=70;            
    }

    [imageScroll setBounces:YES];
    [imageScroll setDelaysContentTouches:YES];
    [imageScroll setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:imageScroll];
    [imageScroll release];
```

and in singleTapGestureCaptured2 method

```
-(void)singleTapGestureCaptured2:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    NSLog(@"image tag or arr index from images array: %d",[[gesture view] tag]);    
}
```

Comment: HI abdullah, thanks for the response. But i think you haven't read my question properly. I need the UIScrollview for scrolling and TTImageview for async loading.

Comment: What I try to say is: you should create UIView every time you create imageView with the frame of image view, then you should add that UIView to scrollview not the imageView, because imageView is inside the UIView and your async loading will work without any trouble.

Comment: Hi abdullah, i didn't see any logic in the solution; but i did give it a try, having a uiview, adding the ttimageview inside the uiview and then adding uiview into the scrollview; still the same, your solution did not work.

Comment: did you add tap gesture on the UIView ??

Comment: yes i did - does'nt work. Anyways, can you explain the logical reason behind your solution?

Comment: UIImageView does not respond to UItaprecognizer but it works fine with NSTouch. So what I do is add image view to uiview as followings and add tap gesture to uiview. check the updates of answer.

Comment: Thanks for the code, that's what i have done previously based on yoru suggestion and it doesn't work. UIImageView does'nt respond to UITapgetsureRecognizer? Then how does it work outside a UIScrollView and why does it work only for the last image inside UIScrollView? 
Anyways, unfortunately, even adding a uiview and a tapgesturerecognizer to it does'nt solve the problem. Any other suggestions?